# How to design database for a queue of users

Tags: java, database

I am building a side project to learn spring boot and react js. I am having problem in designing the database.
The project is about virtual queue. User can select the merchant he/she wants to go and can join in queue of that merchant.
I am having problem in designing the table for queue.
The idea I have is that we will have separate table for user and merchant with all the necessary information and a queue table with merchant_id, user_id,queue_position_of_user.
The problem is that there are different users with different merchant. So should i make separate queue table for each merchant or should i implement all in the same queue table.

The basic design idea I want to follow is to reduce time retrieving data from the database

Comment: Associative Entity or Junction Entity: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity